# C and GTK Passing parameters

Tags: c, gtk3

The following program will not compile. I've reduced the code down to this simple program. I've posted the compile command and its output.

```
#include <gtk/gtk.h>

void update_label(GtkLabel *glab);

void update_label(GtkLabel *glab)
{
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  GtkWidget *lbl;

  gtk_init(&argc, &argv);

  lbl = gtk_label_new("Hi");

  update_label(lbl);

  gtk_main();

  return 0;
}
```

The compiler output is:

```
graeme@graeme-HP-xw4300-Workstation ~/c/label $ gcc `pkg-config --cflags gtk+-3.0` my04.c -o my04 `pkg-config --libs gtk+-3.0`
my04.c: In function ‘main’:
my04.c:17:3: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘update_label’ from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]
   update_label(lbl);
   ^
my04.c:5:6: note: expected ‘struct GtkLabel *’ but argument is of type ‘struct GtkWidget *’
 void update_label(GtkLabel *glab)
      ^
```

Comment: `will not compile`...how do you know?

Comment: If you ask questions about build errors, then please copy-paste the full build log (as text) into the body of the question. Then mark out which lines of code the errors are on, for example with comments in the code.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre So, you're saying, if I say, _I will go_, that also means _I don't want to go_? :(

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Ahh.. got it, you meant "will not" == "doesn't want to", right?

Comment: It's probably because update_label expects a GtkLabel* but you supply a GtkWidget*

Comment: @SouravGhosh yes, of course. Sorry.

Comment: You've a typo in your code, you intended your `lbl` to be of type `GtkLabel *` but typed it out as `GtkWidget *`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You declare `update_label` as accepting `GtkLabel*` argument:

```
void update_label(GtkLabel *glab);
```

On the other hand, you pass it argument `lbl` which is of type `GtkWidget*`:

```
GtkWidget *lbl;
(...)
update_label(lbl);
```

That's why compiler raises error *"passing argument 1 of ‘update_label’ from incompatible pointer type"*, and even explains it further:

```
my04.c:5:6: note: expected ‘struct GtkLabel *’ but argument is of type ‘struct GtkWidget *’
 void update_label(GtkLabel *glab)
```

To solve this, you have to upcast `lbl` to `GtkLabel*`, as that variable points to object which is really a `GtkLabel`:

```
update_label(GTK_LABEL(lbl));
```

https://developer.gnome.org/gobject/stable/gtype-conventions.html

Answer (score 0):

For GTK in C you need a lot of pointer conversions.
For some reason all creator functions return `GtkWidget*` but all the related modifier functions require proper pointers to `GtkLabel*` etc..

For this purpose GTK provides typecast macros.

You can use `GTK_LABEL()` macro to convert your pointer.
For other types of widgets you have `GTK_WINDOW`, `GTK_MENU_ITEM` and much more such macros.

This is rather annyoing in first place.

When it comes to functions from an interface or from parent object "class" (not really OO classes) you need to pick the correct type and cast apropriately anyway.